# How to show complete reducibility from this special case?

Tags: modules, representation-theory

This is a quick question: given a finite group $G$, if we already know that for every $G$-module $M$, the space of invariants $M^G$ is a direct summand of $M$, how to show complete reducibility of $G$-modules? (this is from [a note I'm reading](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Efengt/Lurie_plen2.pdf))

And is this also true for representations of general associative algebra $A$? i.e. If we know that  for any $A$-module $M$, $M^A$ is always a direct summand of $M$, is $A$ semisimple?